# os.system() vs. os.popen() when using bash process substitution: ls: cannot access '/dev/fd/63': No such file or directory

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a Python program that takes a file argument and sends it to a subprocess, using `os.popen()`. It works great for normal files. But it doesn't work when using bash Process Substitution ([short article](https://medium.com/factualopinions/process-substitution-in-bash-739096a2f66d)).

Why does `os.system()` work but `os.popen()` fail for the same command (on Ubuntu)? Here is `run.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

cmd = "ls -l %s" % sys.argv[1]
os.system(cmd)
pipe = os.popen(cmd)
print(pipe.read(), end="")
```

Output:

```sh
# Both os.system("ls -l file") and os.popen("ls -l file") work great
$ run.py file
-rw-r--r-- 1 peter peter 313080 Apr 15 12:27 file
-rw-r--r-- 1 peter peter 313080 Apr 15 12:27 file

# os.system("ls -l /proc/self/fd/11") works great but os.popen("ls -l /proc/self/fd/11") fails
$ run.py <(cat file)
lr-x------ 1 peter peter 64 Apr 15 12:27 /proc/self/fd/11 -> 'pipe:[171197]'
ls: cannot access '/proc/self/fd/11': No such file or directory
```

Does anybody know why `os.popen("ls -l /proc/self/fd/11")` fails like this?

I've created a Perl version, `perl-run.pl`, to be a similar as I could muster to the Python `run.pl` version above, and both Perl's `system()` and `open()` work as I expect:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $cmd = "ls -l $ARGV[0]";
system($cmd);
open(my $i, $cmd . " |");
print <$i>;
```

Output:

```sh
$ perl-run.pl <(cat file) 
lr-x------ 1 peter peter 64 Apr 15 12:27 /proc/self/fd/11 -> 'pipe:[165704]'
lr-x------ 1 peter peter 64 Apr 15 12:27 /proc/self/fd/11 -> pipe:[165704]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `os.popen` method is actually just a wrapper for `subprocess.Popen`. If we look at the documentation for [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), we find:

> If close_fds is true, all file descriptors except 0, 1 and 2 will be closed before the child process is executed. Otherwise when close_fds is false, file descriptors obey their inheritable flag as described in Inheritance of File Descriptors.

This means that when using a shell construct like `<(some command)`, the file descriptor associated with that redirection gets closed before executing the subprocess, so the corresponding `/dev/fd/nn` file disappears.

There's no way to control this flag when calling `os.popen`, but you can instead use the `subprocess` module directly and write something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess
import sys

cmd = "ls -l %s" % sys.argv[1]
os.system(cmd)
pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=False)
stdout, stderr = pipe.communicate()
print(stdout, end="")
```

See the `subprocess` documentation for details on interacting with
`Popen` objects.