# pass on file descriptors to child process with node.js

Tags: node.js, child-process, file-descriptor

In order to use `bashcov` in  one of my projects, I need a way to pass on all file descriptors from node.js to a child process.

I have created these test programs:

```
$ head -n20 m.sh r.js s.sh
==> m.sh <==
#! /usr/bin/env bash

set -e

exec 3<>messages

echo see when we can see the file descriptor we created
echo from main bash program:
ls -l /proc/$$/fd/
echo
echo from bash subprogram called directly:
./s.sh
echo
node r.js ./s.sh

exec 3>&-

==> r.js <==
const run = function(cmd) {
  return require('child_process').spawnSync(cmd[0], cmd.slice(1), {
    stdio: 'inherit',
  });
}

console.log('from javascript program:');
run(['ls', '-l', `/proc/${process.pid}/fd/`]);
console.log('\nfrom bash subprogram called from js:');
run(process.argv.slice(2))


==> s.sh <==
#! /usr/bin/env bash

set -e

ls -l /proc/$$/fd/
```

The main program `m.sh` list all of its file descriptors, and then call a bash program that I have referred to as "subprogram" `s.sh` which also lists all of its fds.  Then I call a js program `r.js` which lists its available fds, and then calls `s.sh` again using the `child_process` lib.

This is the result:

```
$ ./m.sh
see when we can see the file descriptor we created
from main bash program:
total 0
lrwx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 0 -> /dev/pts/2
l-wx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 1 -> pipe:[256648]
lrwx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 2 -> /dev/pts/2
lr-x------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 255 -> /home/me/bashcov/m.sh
lrwx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 3 -> /home/me/bashcov/messages

from bash subprogram called directly:
total 0
lrwx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 0 -> /dev/pts/2
l-wx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 1 -> pipe:[256648]
lrwx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 2 -> /dev/pts/2
lr-x------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 255 -> /home/me/bashcov/s.sh
lrwx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 3 -> /home/me/bashcov/messages

from javascript program:
total 0
lrwx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 0 -> /dev/pts/2
l-wx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 1 -> pipe:[256648]
lrwx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 10 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lr-x------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 11 -> pipe:[256661]
l-wx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 12 -> pipe:[256661]
lrwx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 13 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
lrwx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 14 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lr-x------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 15 -> pipe:[258179]
l-wx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 16 -> pipe:[258179]
lrwx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 17 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
lr-x------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 18 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 19 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lrwx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 2 -> /dev/pts/2
lr-x------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 20 -> pipe:[258182]
l-wx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 21 -> pipe:[258182]
lrwx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 22 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
lrwx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 3 -> /home/me/bashcov/messages
lrwx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 4 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lr-x------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 5 -> pipe:[258177]
l-wx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 6 -> pipe:[258177]
lr-x------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 7 -> pipe:[258178]
l-wx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 8 -> pipe:[258178]
lrwx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 9 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]

from bash subprogram called from js:
total 0
lrwx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 0 -> /dev/pts/2
l-wx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 1 -> pipe:[256648]
lrwx------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 2 -> /dev/pts/2
lr-x------ 1 me me 64 Apr 16 12:16 255 -> /home/me/bashcov/s.sh
```

You can see that inside the `s.sh` when it is called from node.js, it does not have access to file descriptor `3` which I have created.  bash passes it on to the bash program it calls, and the node program it calls, but node does not.

I have just run into this issue with python ([bashcov - does not work if subprogram is called by python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67114020/bashcov-does-not-work-if-subprogram-is-called-by-python)) and the solution turned out to be to add the param `close_fds=False`. ([os.system() vs. os.popen() when using bash process substitution: ls: cannot access '/dev/fd/63': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67107067/os-system-vs-os-popen-when-using-bash-process-substitution-ls-cannot-acce/67108740))

If I replace the js program in this experiment with a ruby or make program, it works fine.

Is there a way to tell node.js's `child_process` to pass all the open file descriptors on the the child_process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `stdio: 'inherit'` with `stdio: [0, 1, 2, 3]`. `'inherit'` is shorthand for `[0, 1, 2]`, per [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio), so if you want FD 3 to be passed too, you need to add it manually. I don't see a way to tell it to inherit every FD other than manually creating an array with all of their numbers.

Comment: if you are using this to get coverage of bash programs you call with bashcov, this worked for me: `stdio: Array(parseInt(process.env.BASH_XTRACEFD + 1)).fill('inherit')`